# raxmon equivalent for load balancer ssl termination on rackspace?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, rackspace-cloud

Looking into [RackSpace SSL](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ssl-termination-on-cloud-load-balancers) termination and realizing [the API](http://docs.rackspace.com/loadbalancers/api/v1.0/clb-devguide/content/Overview-d1e82.html) to configure SSL termination is extremely bare.

Before I get started writing a client, does anyone know if there is something out there already?  Similar to [raxmon](http://docs.rackspace.com/cm/api/v1.0/cm-getting-started/content/using-raxmon.html) for the [Monitoring](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/public/monitoring/)?

Comment: writing the client now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python, you can use [pyrax](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax), the Rackspace Python language bindings, which abstracts the API commands necessary to enable SSL offloading on a Cloud Loadbalancer. There is a sample script provided [here](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/samples/cloud_loadbalancers/ssl_termination.py) that you can use as a template.

Alternatively, the [Rackspace Control Panel](https://mycloud.rackspace.com) allows you to enable SSL offloading via the UI.

Comment: Thanks for this.  We're using PHP, but did find the UI controls sometime after starting on our own implementation.  Frankly we've found the load balancers to be a weak spot in terms of options and the API a bit lacking, but still liking Rackspace on the whole.  Thanks for your answer!